# how to word wrap in normal html textbox?

Tags: html, textbox

i have this text box

```
<p>Event Data :<input  id="data" type="text" wrap="true" value="{{data}}" 
            style="width: 757px; height: 170px" />
    </p>
```

i want it to be multiline
i can't use asp:textbox
is it possible to use exact textbox and make it multiline or

make the text in textbox go **word wrap**

Comment: I think what you want is `wrap="virtual"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
<p>Event Data:
<textarea id="data" style="width: 757px; height: 170px" rows="10" cols="80">{{data}}</textarea>
</p>
```

Hat tip (and +1) to [Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819748/how-to-word-wrap-in-normal-html-textbox/1819789#1819789) for pointing out that `rows` and `cols` are required attributes to `textarea`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<p>Event Data:
<textarea id="data" rows="10" cols="80">{{data}}</textarea>
</p>
```

rows and cols are required attributes.  Don't ask me why.  And if you're going to set the size in CSS, it's generally better to do it in em or % rather than px.

Comment: I now this comment is 9 years old, so this is just a clarification; with HTML5 rows/cols are not strictly required anymore. w3schools, for example says: "The size of a text area can be specified by the cols and rows attributes, or even better; through CSS' height and width properties.".

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want your text values to display as multi-lines, use add a `white-space: pre;` style to the textarea element, making sure to put put the proper line-breaks into the returned `{{data}}`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `<textarea>` with a `wrap` attribute. It is not in any HTML standard but to my knowledge the settings "soft", "hard" and "off" work in all major browsers. Definitely in [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535152%28VS.85%29.aspx). Firefox seems to require a "cols" setting for wrap to work, though.

Comment: What `word-wrap` attribute? http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7

Comment: In which browsers does it not wrap anyway without any such non-standard attribute?