# How to wrap the text coming from httprequest.getparameter in java

Tags: java, html, css, jakarta-ee

I want to wrap the test coming from a textbox as a servlet request and wrap the data while settin the parameter.How can i do this?

Sample code:

```
lModule.setDescription(pRequest.getParameter("Description"));
```

I want to wrap the text of Description.

Please help me in this.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'wrap'?

Comment: @asgs when a word at the end of line is in the middle, it has to be moved to next line automatically.That is called wrap.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking how a parameter from httprequest is related to a wrap issue in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a HTML textbox, one easy way to go is include the rows and columns within the  tag which will enable you to wrap the text.

See this link for more details:
[how to word wrap in normal html textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819748/how-to-word-wrap-in-normal-html-textbox)

The other option is to use a text-area which has a 'wrap' attribute:

The 'wrap' attribute has 3 values:

**
Soft
Hard
Off
**

Soft - sets the wrap to appear only in the HTML form - all line spacing and line breaks are not included when the form is submitted.

Hard - sets the wrap to appear in forms and line spacing and breaks are sent along with the form data.

Off - wrap is turned off and places the text is one ongoing line.

A sample example:

`<textarea cols="20" rows="5" wrap="hard">
 As you can see many times word wrapping is often the desired look for your textareas. Since it makes everything nice and easy to read and preserves line breaks.
</textarea>`

Hope it helps.