# Linebreak in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add line break when the text overflows 
ex. if the text is

```
wwwwwwwwwwwwwww

wwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

which is with in the textarea

the data should be with the line break.
Currently the data it is displaying is

```
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww.
```

I need to show the exact way how the data is entered in textarea.

When the text overflows it moves to next line in the textarea,but when the data is retrieved the line break is not retained. It just displays as a single line 

Or is there any way we can know that overflow occurs so that new line can be added?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. In this case click the `<>` and show the textarea and how you want to display the content. HTML will ignore line breaks not converted to `<br/>`

Comment: Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819748/how-to-word-wrap-in-normal-html-textbox ?

Comment: Try with `<textarea id="yourId"></textarea>`

Comment: Its not the word wrap.. I want the visual line break to retain as it is.. the output should be with the line break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from the below fiddle which applies the line break to each next line 
http://jsfiddle.net/pH79a/218/

html

```
<div>
<textarea rows="5" id="myTextarea" ></textarea>
</div>
<div id="pnlPreview"></div>
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="ApplyLineBreaks('myTextarea');">Apply Line Breaks</button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function ApplyLineBreaks(strTextAreaId) {
var oTextarea = document.getElementById(strTextAreaId);
if (oTextarea.wrap) {
    oTextarea.setAttribute("wrap", "off");
}
else {
    oTextarea.setAttribute("wrap", "off");
    var newArea = oTextarea.cloneNode(true);
    newArea.value = oTextarea.value;
    oTextarea.parentNode.replaceChild(newArea, oTextarea);
    oTextarea = newArea;
}

var strRawValue = oTextarea.value;
oTextarea.value = "";
var nEmptyWidth = oTextarea.scrollWidth;
var nLastWrappingIndex = -1;

function testBreak(strTest) {
    oTextarea.value = strTest;
    return oTextarea.scrollWidth > nEmptyWidth;
}
function findNextBreakLength(strSource, nLeft, nRight) {
    var nCurrent;
    if(typeof(nLeft) == 'undefined') {
        nLeft = 0;
        nRight = -1;
        nCurrent = 64;
    }
    else {
        if (nRight == -1)
            nCurrent = nLeft * 2;
        else if (nRight - nLeft <= 1)
            return Math.max(2, nRight);
        else
            nCurrent = nLeft + (nRight - nLeft) / 2;
    }
    var strTest = strSource.substr(0, nCurrent);
    var bLonger = testBreak(strTest);
    if(bLonger)
        nRight = nCurrent;
    else
    {
        if(nCurrent >= strSource.length)
            return null;
        nLeft = nCurrent;
    }
    return findNextBreakLength(strSource, nLeft, nRight);
}

var i = 0, j;
var strNewValue = "";
while (i < strRawValue.length) {
    var breakOffset = findNextBreakLength(strRawValue.substr(i));
    if (breakOffset === null) {
        strNewValue += strRawValue.substr(i);
        break;
    }
    nLastWrappingIndex = -1;
    var nLineLength = breakOffset - 1;
    for (j = nLineLength - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var curChar = strRawValue.charAt(i + j);
        if (curChar == ' ' || curChar == '-' || curChar == '+') {
            nLineLength = j + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    strNewValue += strRawValue.substr(i, nLineLength) + "\n";
    i += nLineLength;
}
oTextarea.value = strNewValue;
oTextarea.setAttribute("wrap", "");
document.getElementById("pnlPreview").innerHTML = oTextarea.value.replace(new RegExp("\\n", "g"), "<br />");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`word-wrap: break-word` is your friend. Try this code.

```
textarea {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work.. the data still comes in a single line

Answer (score 0):

Try `cols` attribute of the `textarea`

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="40">
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
</textarea>
```

Comment: I need the visual value to be retained with the line break

Comment: what do you mean by a visual line break ?

Comment: I mean when the text overflows the text moves to next line but while retrieveing the value the linebreak is not retained. How to retain that line break

Comment: how is your textarea data getting saved in db table. with linebreaks or just the text alone.

Comment: without line break it is saving .. i need with line break

Comment: @user3510028! which is the datatype of the field in table?

Comment: its varchar in the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171670/discussion-between-hrishikesh-and-user3510028).

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
<input type="text" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">
```

Answer (score 0):

In `PHP` u usually use `nl2br()` function.
Please refer to the below question, I am sure that it will help you!

[jQuery convert line breaks to br (nl2br equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent)

Comment: when the data in textbox overflows the text comes down and it is shown as a two line. but while retrieving the text the data is coming as one line

Comment: Are using `PHP` or `javascript` to retrieve the value ?

Comment: I am using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use word-wrap for textarea reference to below link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Answer (score 0):

This simple line of code can help you with the task:

```
<textarea id="textbox" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```

But you should search it on web and there are many questions with the same context on the stackoverflow itself.

You can try it here but I think it is not needed:

https://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/8f3y5r4d/

I hope this helps.

Comment: no it doesn't work the way I want. On retrieval of data also i should retain the line break not only on display.

Comment: then its not that the code will automatically append `<br>` at every line break, for that you have to press enter give `<br>` manually while writing something in the `textarea`.

Comment: and if you need help on saving special characters, then take reference from this link:
[Populating the textarea with special charcters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037263/populating-a-textarea-with-special-characters)